# C++, Visual Studio 2008, error C2556, C2371

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project and when I try to compile a get lots of errors which are:

```
    Error   11  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::eGetMsg(bool,bool)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eGetMsg(bool,bool)'   c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 663 FsLonPlayer
    Error   12  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::eGetMsg' : redefinition; different basic types    c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 663 FsLonPlayer
    Error   13  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiEncryption(bool)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiEncryption(bool)' c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 716 FsLonPlayer
    Error   14  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::eNiEncryption' : redefinition; different basic types  c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 716 FsLonPlayer
    Error   15  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiGetNextResponse(ldv::RespAddrDtl *,ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte *)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiGetNextResponse(ldv::RespAddrDtl *,ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte *)' c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 741 FsLonPlayer
    Error   16  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::eNiGetNextResponse' : redefinition; different basic types c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 741 FsLonPlayer
    Error   17  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiInit(LPCSTR)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiInit(LPCSTR)' c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 772 FsLonPlayer
    Error   18  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::eNiInit' : redefinition; different basic types    c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 772 FsLonPlayer
    Error   19  error C2264: 'clsNOLDVni::eGetMsg' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called   c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 792 FsLonPlayer
    Error   20  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiSendImmediate(ldv::NI_NoQueueCmd)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiSendImmediate(ldv::NI_NoQueueCmd)'   c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 806 FsLonPlayer
    Error   21  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::eNiSendImmediate' : redefinition; different basic types   c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 806 FsLonPlayer
    Error   22  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiSendMsgWait(ldv::ServiceType,const ldv::SendAddrDtl *,const ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte,ldv::Bool,ldv::Bool,ldv::ComplType *,int *,ldv::RespAddrDtl *,ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte *,ldv::Bits)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiSendMsgWait(ldv::ServiceType,const ldv::SendAddrDtl *,const ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte,ldv::Bool,ldv::Bool,ldv::ComplType *,int *,ldv::RespAddrDtl *,ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte *,ldv::Bits)' c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 842 FsLonPlayer
    Error   23  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::eNiSendMsgWait' : redefinition; different basic types c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 842 FsLonPlayer
    Error   24  error C2264: 'clsNOLDVni::eGetMsg' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called   c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 885 FsLonPlayer
    Error   25  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiSendResponse(ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte,ldv::Bits)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eNiSendResponse(ldv::MsgData *,ldv::Byte,ldv::Bits)' c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 979 FsLonPlayer
    Error   26  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::eNiSendResponse' : redefinition; different basic types    c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 979 FsLonPlayer
    Error   27  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::ePutMsg(void *,short)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::ePutMsg(void *,short)' c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 1007    FsLonPlayer
    Error   28  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::ePutMsg' : redefinition; different basic types    c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 1007    FsLonPlayer
    Error   29  error C2556: 'eNICode clsNOLDVni::ePutMsg(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::ePutMsg(void)' c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 1040    FsLonPlayer
    Error   30  error C2371: 'clsNOLDVni::ePutMsg' : redefinition; different basic types    c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 1040    FsLonPlayer
    Error   31  error C2264: 'clsNOLDVni::ePutMsg' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called   c:\Projects\Edwards SCADA\Components\Agents\LonWorks\Lon Agent Player\clsNewLDV.cpp 1041    FsLonPlayer
```

An example of eGetMsg as defined in the header, and there is only one:

```
    protected:
        eNICode eGetMsg(bool blnWait, bool blnIgnorePending = false);
```

The same function in the cpp file:

```
    eNICode clsNOLDVni::eGetMsg(bool blnWait, bool blnIgnorePending) {
        eNICode eNiResult = NI_OK;

        if ( !blnIgnorePending && mllPending != NULL ) {
    //Got one squirreled away - these messages were received while the application was waiting for 
    //the completion of another pending transaction, and were stored away for processing at a later
    //time. This time is now:
            if ( mllPending->msg.msg_hdr.exp.st == REQUEST ) {
    //Save incoming priority for later use with the response
                ExpAppBuffer* pMsg = &mllPending->msg;
                maryblnReqPriority[pMsg->msg_hdr.exp.tag] = pMsg->msg_hdr.exp.priority;
            }
            const tMsgLL cpCurrent = mllPending;
            mllPending = cpCurrent->pNext;
    //Dispatch the current message:
            memcpy(&mMsgIn, &cpCurrent->msg, sizeof(cpCurrent->msg));
            free(cpCurrent);
        } else {
            time_t tDeadline = time(NULL) + niWAIT_TIME;
    //Loop until the network interface provides a message, or timeout
            for (;;) {
    //Check for network interface input
                const LDVCode cLdvError = mobjLDV.read(&mMsgIn, sizeof(mMsgIn));

                if ( cLdvError == LDV_OK ) {
                    eNiResult = (mMsgIn.ni_hdr.q.q_cmd != niCOMM) ? NI_UPLINK_CMD : NI_OK;
                    break;
                } else if ( cLdvError == LDV_NO_MSG_AVAIL 
                         || cLdvError == LDV_NO_BUFF_AVAIL 
                         || cLdvError == LDV_NO_RESOURCES ) {
                    time_t tNow = time(NULL);

                    if (!blnWait || tNow > tDeadline ) {
                        eNiResult = NI_TIMEOUT;
                        break;
                    } else {
    //Sleep a little while before re-trying:
                        Sleep(niPAUSE_TIME);
                    }
                } else {
                    eNiResult = NI_DRIVER_ERROR;
                }
            }
        }   // end for
        return eNiResult;
    }
```

I'm scratching my head, I can't see anything wrong with either the prototype or the implementation, the class this is contained in is simple, it isn't abstract and isn't derived from anything.  I'm guessing there is something else causing this error as it doesn't appear to be overloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error messages I think *The same function in the cpp file* must be

```
clsNOLDVni::eNICode clsNOLDVni::eGetMsg(bool blnWait, bool blnIgnorePending)
```

You have yet another type `eNICode` declared in your files somewhere. One `eNICode` is declared in the class `clsNOLDVni`, another is declared globally.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how you arrived at this conclusion from the error messages, they don't seem very clear to me, but you are correct!  I am replacing an existing older version of the same class with this version and there were duplicates of the same enumerated type declared in both classes.

Comment: @SPlatten Compiler is kind of doctor, who knows most of our codes problem and tells clearly. What we need is, just *keep calm and listen/ read*. :)